# Javascript: Math.min() returns NaN

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, nan

I'm trying to create a piece of code in Javascript that compares an array of Epoch times (which are just large integers) and I want it to find the smallest, or most historic, time value.

This is what I've written so far but it just returns 'NaN' when I run it.

```
var times = [1501502460000,1501497900000,1501498920000,1501493700000];
lowestTime = Math.min(times);
```

Note that I am using the Math.min() not Math.max().

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you want `Math.min()` to process an **array** of values, you have to use `.apply()`:

```
var lowestTime = Math.min.apply(Math, times);
```

You could also use the new-ish spread syntax:

```
var lowestTime = Math.min(... times);
```

but that doesn't work in all environments.

When you pass the array directly, the first thing `Math.min()` does is try to convert it to a number because that's what it expects: individual numbers. When that happens, through a round-about process the resulting value will be `NaN`.

Comment: It should be noted that the reason that you must do this is because `Math.min` does not take an array as a parameter. It takes a comma separated list of n parameters, which is why `.apply()` and `...` work - they convert an array to a comma separated list of values.